# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'mailer')

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, nodemon

I'm trying to set up an email sending using nodemon(^2.0.22) and nodemailer(^6.9.3).

It turns out that when trying to send the email I come across this error: "TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'mailer')" On line 45 of index.js of the nodemailer lib. When accessing this line, we have the following code: this.transporter.mailer = this;

I cannot identify what is causing this error. I'm going to pass here the HTML of my form, the header of my index.js and the route that sends the emails, so that you can help me.

Thanks.

**HTML**

```
              <div id="tab2Content" class="tab-content">
                <form id="formulario" action="/send" method="POST" role="form" enctype="Content-Type">
                <div class="row">
                    <div>
                      <h2>Dados do solicitante</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio-container">
                      <label for="sigSim">Desejo não me identificar</label> <input type="radio" name="sigilo" id="sigSim" value="com_sigilo" required="" onchange="ocultarDivs()"> <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio-container">
                      <label id="lblMaior" for="sigNao">Desejo me identificar, mostrando os meus dados</label> <input type="radio" name="sigilo" id="sigNao" value="sem_sigilo" required="" checked onchange="ocultarDivs()">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    
                  <fieldset id="dados_user">
                    <hr class="col-md-7 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                      <label for="name">Nome: </label>
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                      <label for="email">E-mail: </label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                      <label for="cep">CEP: </label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cep" id="cep" value="" size="10" maxlength="9" onblur="pesquisacep(this.value);" placeholder="Digite apenas números" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0" id="rua_num">
                      <div id="div_ende" class="col-md-10">
                        <label for="endereco">Rua: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control " name="endereco" id="rua" placeholder="" >
                      </div>
                      <div >
                        <label for="numero">N°: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control " name="numero" id="numero" placeholder="" >
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                      <label for="complemento">Complemento: </label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control " name="complemento" id="complemento" placeholder="" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                      <label for="bairro">Bairro: </label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bairro" id="bairro" placeholder="" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                      <label for="cidade">Cidade: </label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cidade" id="cidade" placeholder="" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                      <label for="uf">Estado: </label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="uf" id="uf" placeholder="" >
                    </div>
                    <!-- <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                      <label for="fixo">Telefone Fixo: </label>
                      <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="fixo" id="fixo" placeholder="" required="false">
                    </div> -->
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                      <label for="celular">Telefone Celular: </label>
                      <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="celular" id="celular" placeholder="" >
                    </div>
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
                <br>
                <hr class="col-md-7 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
              <div class="form-group mt-6">
                <div>
                  <h2>Dados da solicitação</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                  <!-- alterar esse campo para lista de categoria: Solicitação, Elogio, Sugestão, Reclamação e Denúncia -->
                  <label for="categoria">Categoria: </label>
                  <select name="categoria" id="categoria" class="form-select-sm">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione uma categoria...</option>
                    <option value="Solicitação">Solicitação</option>
                    <option value="Reclamacao">Reclamação</option>
                    <option value="Denúncia">Denúncia</option>
                    <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <fieldset id="dados_user">
                  <div class="col-md-7 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0" >
                    <label for="resposta" id="lblresposta">Como deseja receber a resposta: </label>
                    <!-- alterar esse campo para lista de como deseja receber a resposta: e-mail, carta, oficio, presencial, whatsapp, sem resposta -->
                    <select name="resposta" id="resposta" class="form-select-sm">
                      <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione uma resposta...</option>
                      <option value="E-mail">E-mail</option>
                      <option value="Ligação">Ligação</option>
                      <option value="Presencial">Presencial</option>
                      <option value="Whatsapp">Whatsapp</option>
                      <option value="Sem resposta">Sem Resposta</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </div>
              <br>
              <hr class="col-md-7 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
              <div class="form-group mt-3">
                <div>
                  <h2>Mensagem</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-7 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                  <label for="assunto">Assunto: </label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="assunto" id="assunto" placeholder="" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                  <label for="arquivo">Arquivo: </label>
                  <input type="file" multiple accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg,.bitmap,.doc,.docx,.pdf,.xls,.xlsx" class="form-control" name="arquivo" id="arquivo" placeholder="" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                  <label for="mensagem">Mensagem: </label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" name="mensagem" id="mensagem" rows="7" placeholder="" required=""></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br>
              
              <input type="checkbox" id="lgpdCheckbox" name="lgpdCheckbox">
              <label for="lgpdCheckbox">Li e concordo com os <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#pdfModal">termos de consentimento da LGPD</a></label>
              <br>
              <br>
              <div class="col-md-7 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0 text-center"><button id="enviar" name="btn_ouvidoria" value="ouvidoria" type="submit">Enviar mensagem</button></div>
              </form>
            </div>
```

**the header of my index.js**

```
// Importa o módulo express para esse arquivo
const express = require("express");
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const { url } = require("inspector");
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer")
const fs = require('fs');
const Swal = require('sweetalert2');
const ejs = require("ejs");
require("dotenv").config();

const FileType = require('file-type');

// Instancia uma referência do express no projeto
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5150; // Const para armanezar a porta do servidor
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

const SMTPTransport = require("nodemailer/lib/smtp-transport");
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body></body></html>');
const doc = dom.window.document;

const smtp = process.env.SMTP
const user_O = process.env.EMAIL_OUVIDORIA
const user_C = process.env.EMAIL_CONTATO
const pass = process.env.SENHA
const porta = process.env.PORTA
```

**Route of send e-mail**

```
app.post("/send", (req, res) =>{

  app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send('Erro interno do servidor');
  });

    function procurarValor(x, lista) {
        if (lista.includes(x)) {
          return "Encontrado";
        } else {
          return "Não encontrado";
        }
      }

console.log('inicio do codigo')
    const{name, email, cep, endereco, numero, complemento, bairro, cidade, uf, celular, categoria, resposta, assunto, mensagem} = req.body;

    const btn = req.body.btn_ouvidoria;
      console.log(req.body)
      let recebedor = ""
      let permissao = ""
      let remetente = ""
    
      console.log(user_O)
      console.log(pass)
    if (btn == "ouvidoria"){
      console.log('acessou o if do btn ouvidoria')
        recebedor = "ouvidoria@ezco.com.br";
        permissao = req.body.sigilo;
        

        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport( 
          console.log('acessou a criação do transporter'),
          new SMTPTransport({
          
          host: smtp,
          port: Number(porta),
          auth: JSON.stringify({user: user_O, pass: pass})
      }));  
  
      console.log('saiu do transporter');
      console.log(transporter.host, transporter.port, transporter.user, transporter.pass, transporter.auth, transporter.secure)
      transporter.verify(function(error, success) {
        if (error) {
          console.log('Erro na conexão SSL/TLS:', error);
        } else {
          console.log('Conexão SSL/TLS estabelecida com sucesso');
        }
      });
      console.log('Final do id do btn ouvidoria')
        // remetente = user_O;
    } else if (btn === "fale_conosco"){
       recebedor = "contato@ezco.com.br";
       permissao = req.body.sigilo2;

       const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport( new SMTPTransport({
        host: smtp,
        port: Number(465),
        user: process.env.EMAIL_CONTATO,
        pass: process.env.SENHA,
        auth: {user, pass},
        secure: true
    }));  

    transporter.verify(function(error, success) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Erro na conexão SSL/TLS:', error);
      } else {
        console.log('Conexão SSL/TLS estabelecida com sucesso');
      }
    });

      //  remetente = user_C;
    }


    
    console.log('começo da lista de cidades')
    let cidades = [
        'Abatiá',
        'Andirá',
        'Bandeirantes',
        'Barra do Jacaré',
        'Cambará',
        'Carlópolis',
        'Congonhinhas',
        'Conselheiro Mairinck',
        'Cornélio Procópio',
        'Figueira',
        'Guapirama',
        'Ibaiti',
        'Itambaracá',
        'Jaboti',
        'Jacarezinho',
        'Japira',
        'Joaquim Távora',
        'Jundiaí do Sul',
        'Leópolis',
        'Nova América da Colina',
        'Nova Fátima',
        'Nova Santa Bárbara',
        'Pinhalão',
        'Quatiguá',
        'Rancho Alegre',
        'Ribeirão Claro',
        'Ribeirão do Pinhal',
        'Salto do Itararé',
        'Santa Amélia',
        'Santa Cecília do Pavão',
        'Santa Mariana',
        'Santana do Itararé',
        'Santo Antônio da Platina',
        'Santo Antônio do Paraíso',
        'São Jerônimo da Serra',
        'São José da Boa Vista',
        'São Sebastião da Amoreira',
        'Sapopema',
        'Sertaneja',
        'Siqueira Campos',
        'Tomazina',
        'Uraí',
        'Wenceslau Braz'
      ]
      console.log('final da lista de cidades')
      // const anexo = req.files.map((arquivo) => ({
      //   filename: arquivo.originalname,
      //   path: arquivo.path,
      // }));

      // const totalSize = req.files.reduce((sum, file) => sum + file.size, 0);

      // const limiteTamanho = 20 * 1024 * 1024; // 20MB

    // Verifica se a soma dos tamanhos excede o limite
    // if (totalSize > limiteTamanho) {
        // Lidar com o limite excedido
        
      //  var exibirAlerta = true;
      //  res.render('ouvidoria', { exibirAlerta: exibirAlerta });

        //apaga os arquivos que foram carregados
        // req.files.forEach(arquivo => {
        //     fs.unlink(arquivo.path, (error) => {
        //         if (error) {
        //           console.error('Erro ao excluir o arquivo:', error);
        //         } else {
        //           console.log('Arquivo excluído com sucesso.');
        //         }
        //       });
        // });
        // return; // Encerra a função para evitar o envio do e-mail
    // }

    if (permissao == "com_sigilo" || permissao == "com_sigilo2"){
      console.log('inicio do codigo com sigilo')
        transporter.sendMail({
            from: remetente,
            to: recebedor,
            subject: `${categoria}: ${assunto}`,
            text: 
           `Mensagem: ${mensagem}`
            // attachments: anexo,
        }).then(info =>{
          console.log('inicio do codigo then de envio')
            // req.files.forEach(arquivo => {
            //     fs.unlink(arquivo.path, (error) => {
            //         if (error) {
            //           console.error('Erro ao excluir o arquivo:', error);
            //         } else {
            //           console.log('Arquivo excluído com sucesso.');
            //         }
            //       });
            //   });
              
            res.render("confirmacao_sem_resp")
        }).catch(error =>{
          console.log('inicio do codigo catch de envio')
            // req.files.forEach(arquivo => {
            //     fs.unlink(arquivo.path, (error) => {
            //         if (error) {
            //           console.error('Erro ao excluir o arquivo:', error);
            //         } else {
            //           console.log('Arquivo excluído com sucesso.');
            //         }
            //       });
            //   });

            // res.send(error)
            res.render("confirmacao_erro")
        })
    }else if (permissao == "sem_sigilo" || permissao == "sem_sigilo2"){
        let resultado = procurarValor(`${cidade}`, cidades);
        let regiao = ""
        if (resultado = "Encontrado"){
            regiao = "Norte Pioneiro"
           }else{
            regiao = "Sem região"
           }
    transporter.sendMail({
        from: remetente,
        to: recebedor,
        replyTo: email,
        subject: `${regiao} - ${categoria}: ${assunto}`,
        text: 
       `Nome:   ${name}
E-mail de contato: ${email}
CEP: ${cep}
Endereço: ${endereco}, ${numero} - ${complemento} - ${bairro} - ${cidade} - ${uf}
Telefone celular: ${celular}
Prefere que seja respondido via: ${resposta}
Mensagem: ${mensagem}`
        // attachments: anexo,
    }).then(info =>{

            // req.files.forEach(arquivo => {
            //     fs.unlink(arquivo.path, (error) => {
            //         if (error) {
            //           console.error('Erro ao excluir o arquivo:', error);
            //         } else {
            //           console.log('Arquivo excluído com sucesso.');
            //         }
            //       });
            //   });

        res.render("confirmacao_com_resp")

    }).catch(error =>{

        // req.files.forEach(arquivo => {
        //     fs.unlink(arquivo.path, (error) => {
        //         if (error) {
        //           console.error('Erro ao excluir o arquivo:', error);
        //         } else {
        //           console.log('Arquivo excluído com sucesso.');
        //         }
        //       });
          // });

        res.render("confirmacao_erro")
    })
}



});
```

I've already searched the internet, in several places, including ChatGPT for the reason for this problem. Most of them point me to credential errors, however the credentials are set and checked.

Comment: try setting auth to json string such as `auth: JSON.stringify({user: user_O, pass: pass})`

Comment: please add more code, thanks

Comment: JSON.stringify kept giving the same error. Do you want me to post the entire route of sending the email?

Comment: OP yes please...

Comment: you need to use  Node.js@v6.0.0 to use this library properly. else you could get some issues

Comment: also take a look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer)

Comment: my node.js version is 20.1.0, i'll change to test.

Comment: I installed the version closest to 6.0.0 that I found on the site (https://nodejs.org/pt-br/download/releases) which was 6.17.1

using NVM I configured it to be the default version of my project, but even so the error persists.

Comment: use node v20.1 and just use another mailer library

Comment: save yourself the headache , use [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs)

Comment: I tried to use the lib you indicated but I had several problems too. Finally Matheus Haas, gave me a light regarding my previous code. As I commented below, I applied his suggestion and it worked. But anyway, I also want to thank you for your willingness to help me and for your time spent trying to understand and solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the syntax of nodemailer.createTransport(). According to the [documentation](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/), there is no need to pass new SMTPTransport as an argument.

The expected syntax should look like this:

```
nodemailer.createTransport({
  pool: true,
  host: "smtp.example.com",
  port: 465,
  secure: true, // use TLS
  auth: {
    user: "username",
    pass: "password",
  },
});
```

By failing to retrieve a transporter, the values returns as undefined, and this.transporter.mailer = this; will break because undefined has no "mailer" attribute.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what was crashing. Regular text sending is ok, but now I'm having problems with attachments, however I'm still studying what are the causes of this new error But the one in this topic is solved. Thanks again.